# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Internal.callEngineGetConnection

Tags: java, android, networking, okhttp

I recently updated `okhttp` from 2.4.0 to 2.7.5 and after starting the `android` app tried to connect and gave me the following **error**:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
>                                                                        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Internal.callEngineGetConnection
>                                                                            at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.ws.WebSocketCall.createWebSocket(WebSocketCall.java:154)
>                                                                            at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.ws.WebSocketCall.access$000(WebSocketCall.java:42)
>                                                                            at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.ws.WebSocketCall$1.onResponse(WebSocketCall.java:102)
>                                                                            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:177)
>                                                                            at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
>                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just updated to okhttp 3.2.0 and it seems working